# Flexible PHP / MySQL pagination

Tags: php, mysql, function, pagination

On my website I have quite a lot of pages that need to be paginated. I have solution for that, but it requires to put pagination function in each page. I searched for something flexible like having pagination function in one file (say pagination.php) and use it to paginate various data from database, so different `mysql_queries` and html output. But I was not able to find anything useful.

So could anyone please suggest php pagination function that would be flexible, so paginate data from different queries and outputs that are established on different pages.

Comment: So the pages in the pagination interface you want to make actually represent separate files? Meaning the links in the pagination will actually got to different files on the server?

Comment: Sort of, something I was looking for would go like this: say I have file with pagination function called pagination.php, I will include it on other pages e.g. newPost.php, modPost.php and oldPost.php. I need to than paginate mySql output from these pages via function established in pagination.php file. So I gues feeding different values to that function. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, so you are actually looking for the normal type of pagination, one that presents a subset of the possible content items, which are determined from a database query, on a page but provides the interface to access more of the full set of content items. You just mention the other pages because you need to be able to reuse the pagination code for the various collections of content items presented on those other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several examples on the web to get you started, thats where I'd start:

- http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=pagination&x=0&y=0&go_search=1
- http://www.phpsnaps.com/snaps/view/php-pagination-class/
- http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10283679
- http://phpsense.com/2007/php-pagination-script/

Comment: +1 that pagination class in the last link is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. PHP frameworks like Zend or Joomla have their own solutions. If you don't use any PHP framework you will probably need to develop your own solution (your own library). Once I did it using javascript library "datatables", with my own server-side code. Examples on this can be found [here](http://datatables.net/examples/) in section "Server-side processing".

Comment: Uff a lot of stuff to look, Thnx for the link I'll explore it now )))